# nginx how to remove suffix to static file location

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I am using nginx to server static image files. Within my directory, all images are stored without an extension. For example: `abcdefg.png` will be stored as `/opt/file/ab/cdefg`. And the image url is `http://example.com/file/ab/cdefg.png`.

If the url is `http://example.com/file/ab/cdefg`, the following configuration works. But it doesn't work for url `http://example.com/file/ab/cdefg.png`

```
    location /file/ {
      root /opt/;
      add_header  Content-Disposition attachment;
      add_header  Content-Type application/octet-stream;
    }
```

Comment: Are only PNG files stored under `/opt/files/`? You could add `rewrite ^(.*)\.png$ $1 break;`

Comment: It is possible to rewrite other suffixes at the same time?

Comment: `rewrite ^(.*)(\.png|\.jpg)$ $1 break;` works